# C library version conflicts, how to manage?

Tags: c, debian

I making C application. In build, I specify

```
LIBS=-lcrypto -lcurl
```

I get warning message,

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.2, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so, may conflict with libcrypto.so.1.1
```

By default, -lcrypto is having relationship to 1.1 version. Libcurl depend on 1.0.2 version. I Make him quiet like

```
LIBS=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2  -lcurl
```

But then functionality in included header `#include <openssl/crypto.h>` betrays linked version. Header has relationship with 1.1 version, not 1.0.2.

I wish for advices on how to manage problem. I depend on system CURL library, but it has dependency on version of OpenSSL that I not want. What to do?

**Edit:** Clarification: I do not wish to recompile CURL, if it would help. Is this common "Dependency hell" scenario?

**Edit 2:** Tracking down my so files, I find this,

```
$ dpkg --list | grep libssl1
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                     1.0.1t-1+deb8u6                      amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64                     1.0.2k-1                             amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.1:amd64                       1.1.0e-1                             amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries

$ apt-file list libssl1.0.0
# Nobody! Strange?
$ apt-file list libssl1.0.2 | grep libcrypto
libssl1.0.2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2
$ apt-file list libssl1.1 | grep libcrypto
libssl1.1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcrypto*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4799548 Feb 16 17:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Feb 16 17:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2066816 Jan 26 23:40 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2492192 Jan 26 15:39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2686448 Feb 16 17:57 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcurl*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1059312 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      19 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.3 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4 -> libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  518560 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4.4.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     951 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Feb 21 22:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so | grep libcrypto
    libcrypto.so.1.0.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 (0x00007fd97750a000)
```

As can see, last line demonstrates Debian package relies on this 1.0.2. When examining reverse dependencies on with `apt-cache showpkg libssl1.0.2` I see great many things. Same for 1.1 version, it seems Debian enjoys both.

Comment: You're not stating precisely how you build things. I've never seen `LIBS`; I know about `-L` instead.

Comment: If the header files are a problem, you may have to search the package manager for the appropriate libcrypto version.

Comment: Further: it seems very odd that you'd have libcrypto 1.1 installed, but your libcurl depends on 1.0.2. That means your debian version is in conflict with itself. That doesn't seem right; what Debian version is this? Did you install anything yourself?

Comment: No, it's not a common problem.  Normally, you have the write files around so that the version problem doesn't manifest itself.  Superficially, you might need to install the 1.0.2 (old) SSL code for your Curl library to link with (a `libcrypto.1.0.2.so` file, or thereabouts), while the rest of your systems runs with the more recent, more secure 1.1 version of the SSL library.  Or you recompile your Curl library to use the current SSL library.  But the versioning normally allows you to avoid seeing such problems.  I suspect you don't have the 1.0.2 version installed, so it uses the 1.1 version.

Comment: Hello - thank you for comments. `LIBS` a Makefile variable included in compiler command. I new in Linux - I installed Debian 8. It has old packages, I made upgrade to testing ("stretch"). apt made no angry in me. I am new inside Linux - but I hope if packages in bad state, I get errors?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thank you confirming my guessing. I have 1.0.2 installed (how otherwise it exist in lib directory?). `$ dpkg --list|grep libssl1
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                     1.0.1t-1+deb8u6                      amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.2:amd64                     1.0.2k-1                             amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libssl1.1:amd64                       1.1.0e-1                             amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries`

Comment: "Confirming" would be putting my own guesswork a bit strongly.  You should add the extra information to the question where you can format it more cleanly (readably).  If I'm disentangling it correctly, you have 1.0.0, 1.0.2 and 1.1.0 installed?  You may end up having to track down the actual `.so` file names — at least, that's what I'd want to do — if only to check what the multitude of symlinks involved are actually pointing at.

Comment: Have you read the libcurl documentation about building applications using it?  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html  contains recommended building methodology.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: :) Default libcurl points to 1.1 version, 1.0.2 lives inside for other dependents in Debian apparently (I update question).

Comment: @TonyB Thank you - I did. I guess you make comment for `curl-config`, while I investigated, I took it's output for this `--libs` and placed it manually (it only -lcurl)

Comment: When you specify `-lcrypto`, the linker looks for `libcrypto.so` and that links to `libcrypto.so.1.1` (symlink).  So, to link 'correctly' with `libcrypto.so.1.0.2`, I think you'll need to replace your `-lcrypto` with `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2`.  At least, doing that would allow you to see whether you get rid of the messages.  I don't think it's a good long term solution, but then again, I'm not sure what the approved technique is.

Comment: If you don't share your machine, you could consider relinking `libcrypto.so` to `libcrypto.so.1.0.2` when you're doing the link with the Curl lib, and reinstating the link to `libcrypto.so.1.1` afterwards. That's also horrid, but avoids embedding the library path name in the executable, which is good if the code will be used on other machines. Personally, I think you should upgrade the Curl library to use the most recent available SSL library. That avoids most problems and gets you the security bug fixes too. Presumably you have good reasons not to do it, but I can't imagine what they are.

Comment: HI @JonathanLeffler. I did make direct link to 1.0.2 originally, and got rid of message, but it not right library for ssl headers installed (missing feature, more bugs). I felt building CURL would be only option, because Debian offer no updates yet for me. Thank you for exploration into my problem, it was very kind!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same warning as you after upgrading from Debian 8 (jessie) to Debian 9 (stretch).  The fix that worked for me is:

```
apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this when searching for a similar issue.  In my case, it turned out to be a CMakeLists.txt whose link_directories were missing /usr/local/lib and were thus defaulting to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0.  The confusing error message led me to believe the problem was the opposite of what I corrected by providing the missing path.